# Is it possible to use 'a handful' as a subject in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

Hello~ I'm studying English in Korea through my English textbook.

Here are original question and answer in my book.

Q. Pardon me, Is this the only Korean restaurant nearby?

A. No way, a handful are within a stone's throw of here.

By the way, I have a question about usage of 'a handful' as a subject.

Is it possible to use 'a handful' rather than 'a handful of noun'?

Should it be the subject like 'a handful of Korean restaurants'?

Comment: You have two questions. The first is syntactical: Can the word *handful* be a subject? Of course. *Handful* is a noun, and nouns serve as subjects of English sentences. The second is semantic: Will English speakers understand that the *handful* of A refers to Korean restaurants of Q. Again the answer is yes. This is a common shorthand. You may also expand the answer as you suggested.

Comment: Notice also that “a handful” often refers to a small number. So, if there were only a few Korean restaurants nearby but more further away your question might be answered like this: *Q: Is this the only Korean restaurant nearby?  A: No, there are a handful of others around here, but you’ll find heaps more down there along the main road, too.”*